# Copy and paste Clipboard from different application

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I need to copy info from one application and paste it to another..
or get info from clipboard somehow. I know how to send `ctrl-r` to that application and it runs.
also I want to send `ctrl-c` but it does nothing.  I have some info in clipboard(after program finishing it is still there) and I try to paste data to notepad. it doesn't run too. I found some thinks on web, but I don't know how to run it. `ctrl-v` only writes `v` into notepad.

this is code I have:

```
{
    INPUT Refrk1;
    INPUT Refrk2;
    INPUT Refrk3;
    INPUT Refrk4;
    INPUT Inputs[2];


    Refrk1.type = 1;
    Refrk1.ki.wVk = 0x11;
    Refrk1.ki.wScan = 0;    
    Refrk1.ki.dwFlags = 0;  
    Refrk1.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    Refrk1.ki.time = 1;
    Refrk2.type = 1;
    Refrk2.ki.wVk =0x43;
    Refrk2.ki.wScan = 0;    
    Refrk2.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    Refrk2.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    Refrk2.ki.time = 0;
    Refrk3.type = 1;
    Refrk3.ki.wVk =0x56;
    Refrk3.ki.wScan = 0;    
    Refrk3.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    Refrk3.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    Refrk3.ki.time = 0;

    Refrk4.type = 1;
    Refrk4.ki.wVk =0x0D;
    Refrk4.ki.wScan = 0;    
    Refrk4.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    Refrk4.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    Refrk4.ki.time = 0;


    ShowWindow(hAMIDST, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    SetForegroundWindow(hAMIDST);

    SendInput(2, Inputs,sizeof(Inputs[2]));
    Refrk1.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    Refrk2.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    Inputs[0] = Refrk1;
    Inputs[1] = Refrk2;
    SendInput(2, Inputs,sizeof(Inputs[2]));

    ShowWindow(hNOTE, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    SetForegroundWindow(hNOTE);


    Inputs[0] = Refrk1;
    Inputs[1] = Refrk3;
    SendInput(2, Inputs,sizeof(Inputs[2]));
    Sleep(10);
    Refrk1.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    Refrk3.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    Inputs[1] = Refrk1;
    Inputs[0] = Refrk3;
    SendInput(2, Inputs,sizeof(Inputs[2]));

    SendInput(1, &Refrk4,sizeof(INPUT));
    Refrk4.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &Refrk4,sizeof(INPUT));

    ShowWindow(hAMIDST, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    SetForegroundWindow(hAMIDST);
}
```

`ctrl-r` and `ctrl-c` are hotkeys in that program. but `ctrl-c` doesn't run.
I found that I need to somehow control clipboard but I don't know how.
It is not running. OpenClipboard etc. and I need to do it with sending `ctrl-c` while this is hotkey in that application and text is not in the window but it copies needed info to clipboard.

Comment: I don't think keystroke generation is a good idea. You have window handles, so you can better send [registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages to the windows from which you want to copy information and to which you want to paste. You need to include the handlers for these messages into the corresponding message maps. Also you should read about Windows clipboard [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it provides an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipboard has an API. Your application will define, what has to be transferred, e.g. as text, bitmap, or something else. You need to get a book or [on-line tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2242/Using-the-Clipboard-Part-I-Transferring-Simple-Tex).